# SQL Server import data from flat file: 0xc02020a1 Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, encoding

I exported data from one `SQL Server` table into `csv` file and now I wanted to import this file into second table in another database.
A the begin I choosed coding as Unicode:
[image: code page of source]

I tried as ANSI - Latin 1 but the error was the same. I think that with truncating is everything ok, because table is the like in source table:
[image]

Source table page coding is:

```
CREATE DATABASE [source-database]  (EDITION = 'Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S3', MAXSIZE = 200 GB) WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
GO
```

I cannot import data because I get error:

```
Executing (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "JobName" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - Job1_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[JobName]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - Job1_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[JobName]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\tasks\xxxxx\Job1.csv" on data row 5.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
 
Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Job1_csv returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Only JobName column is wrong.

Comment: You should ask this on serverfault

Comment: Please supply a [mcve]. At the very least, let's have the bad row

Comment: I'm closing that bug, because I imported using export data to insert statements. I don't know what was the reason of above error, the file was very big